# Careers 2.0: Show all experience by default

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Most recruiters that view my profile don't see the little "show all" button or expandable arrow > for my experience. This has been horrible for me and I'm having to write in my Personal statement "MAKE SURE TO CLICK show all"

My entire profile should be expanded by default so people can see what I've done

Comment: Valid request, but it's not a bug.